# How can I categorize multiple data.frame list more efficiently?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to categorize list of data.frame with threshold, intend to get different set of data.frame as an output. However, tried to use some useful function from dplyr, tidyr packages to achieve my desired output, but couldn't produce desired data.frame list. I am bit of new of using dplyr, tidyr packages, still learning its vignette. Because I have more than two list of data.frame that needed to be classified, so taking multiple data.frame list as an input for my function, then I intend to classify each data.frame by its `pos.score` column, so final output could be list of data.frame. How can I make this happen by using dplyr, or tidyr package ? Any way to get my expected output ? Can any one give me possible idea to make this happen ? Thanks a lot

reproducible data.frame:

```
Qualified <- list(
  hotan = data.frame( begin=seq(1, by=6, len=20), end=seq(4, by=6, len=20), pos.score=sample(30, 20)),
  aksu = data.frame( begin=seq(3, by=9, len=15), end=seq(6, by=9, len=15), pos.score=sample(28, 15)),
  korla = data.frame( begin=seq(6, by=8, len=18), end=seq(11, by=8, len=18), pos.score=sample(22, 18))
)

UnQualified <- list(
  hotan = data.frame( begin=seq(9, by=12, len=30), end=seq(14, by=12, len=30), pos.score=sample(35, 30)),
  aksu = data.frame( begin=seq(13, by=10, len=20), end=seq(19, by=10, len=20), pos.score=sample(34, 20)),
  korla = data.frame( begin=seq(23, by=11, len=24), end=seq(31, by=11, len=24), pos.score=sample(27, 24))
)
```

so this is the simplest function how to categorize for one data.frame list :

```
func <- function(dfList, threshold) {
  catg <- lapply(dfList, function(elm) {
    res <- split(elm, ifelse(elm$pos.score >=threshold, "valid", "invalid"))
  })
  return(catg)
}
```

but using this function to each list of data.frame can't be desired. I am seeking more programmatic, dynamic solution that merging two or more data.frame into one, then categorize each with given threshold. How can I make this happen more efficiently ? Any idea please ?

my desired output, is list of data.frame as follows:

```
$hotan.valid.Qualified
$hotan.invalid.Qualified
$hotan.valid.UnQualified
$hotan.invalid.UnQualified
$aksu.valid.Qualified
$aksu.invalid.Qualified
$aksu.valid.UnQualified
$aksu.invalid.UnQualified
$korla.valid.Qualified
$korla.invalid.Qualified
$korla.valid.UnQualified
$korla.invalid.UnQualified
```

How can I get my expected output? Any way to produce this output ?

Comment: Why do you need multiple datases.  Wouldn't it be better to have a single dataset with a grouping variable for each list element

Comment: Yeah, if efficiency is your concern, stack the data sets: `dplyr::bind_rows(c(Qualified = Qualified, Unqualified = UnQualified), .id = "id")`

Comment: @akrun  because I got two list of data.frame as an output from one of my function, so I intend to merge them as one single dataset, then classify each by its pos.score column. How can I make this happen ?Could you elaborate your answer please ? Thank you very much

Comment: Well, you're free to try it before hearing any motivation for it, y'know, but: R, dplyr and data.table all work well with long-form data. There are many by-group operations that will be much simpler and more efficient in a single table.

Comment: @Frank  I am bit of new of using dplyr, data.table packages. Yes, I did try of using bind_rows to get single dataset, but can't produce my desired output. how can I get my desired result?

Comment: You misunderstand. I am suggesting that you target a different result because there's not much point having a list of data sets with names you have to parse to work with.

Comment: What threshold value did you use?

Comment: I'm with Frank on this. Just put all your data in one frame. The work is much easier when you use a single space. Like trying to complete a single jigsaw puzzle on a bedside table, a coffee table, and an ottoman instead of just clearing off the dining room table.

Comment: @leerssej Yes, that's why I am trying to do, getting one single data table can be done, but I can't produce my desired output efficiently, I tried several ways already. sorry for my naive question. Any solution on that ?

Comment: Yup! Just a sec: working on it. Thanks for the threshold value.

Comment: but I realize now that your sample already has had `*func()*` applied to it to segregate the data by catg: simpler solution is ready then.

Comment: You don't want to split a single dataframe up into little tidbits: see analogy above about doing a jigsaw puzzle on ten different surfaces. Instead, please read Hadley's paper linked in the answer. It offers really helpful guidance in making the transition towards thinking on a dataframe level.

Comment: Sorry, now I see that I was indeed in need of Threshold! Got sleepy there I guess. Adding that in and will update answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating @Franks comment in the OP with additional tidyverse to clean things up further, here you go:

```
ALLdata <- 
    bind_rows(c(Qualified = Qualified, Unqualified = UnQualified), .id = "id") %>% 
    separate(id, c("Catg", "Name")) %>%
    mutate(elm = ifelse(pos.score >= 18, "valid", "invalid")) %>% 
    arrange(Name, Catg, desc(elm))
```

Which gets you the data all together in one happy data frame. Then you can start to do real magic to it: as per the source book of spells found [here](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf).

I am imagining your next step from here would be to do a summary on all the results. Keeping all the data in one dataframe will make that next step much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a tour through R base functions: `setNames`, `append`, `paste`, `sapply`, `outer`, `order`, `c`:

```
# APPEND BOTH DF LISTS, SUFFIXING TYPE IN NAME
dfList <- setNames(Qualified, paste(names(Qualified), "Qualified", sep="."))
dfList <- append(dfList, setNames(UnQualified, 
                                  paste(names(UnQualified), "UnQualified", sep=".")))

# USER DEFINED FUNCTION
func <- function(elm, n, threshold) {
  res <- split(elm, ifelse(elm$pos.score >= threshold, "valid", "invalid"))[n]
  return(res)
}

# SAPPLY TO NESTED MATRIX FORM [2 X 6]
finalList <- sapply(dfList, func, threshold=15, seq(2))

# MIGRATE TO LIST FORM WITH VALID/INVALID SUFFIX
finalList <- setNames(append(finalList[1,], finalList[2,]),
                      c(outer(names(dfList), c("valid", "invalid"), paste, sep=".")))

# ALPHABETIC ORDER OF NAMED ELEMENTS
finalList <- finalList[order(names(finalList))]
```

Comment: how can I make your solution more dynamic ? Could you give me possible idea on this needs? Thank you :)

Comment: What do you mean dynamic? What components will change?

Comment: Dear Parfait, your answer is easy to use, just using base R to make this happen. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Awwww! Base R lost again. Do note the other dplyr answer is structurally different from this one of dataframe lists not just one data frame of added columns which per your comments above, the df list was desired result. Nonetheless, happy coding!